# Map flat object to composed object with mapstruct

Tags: mapstruct

Why doesn't this generate mapping code automatically, when the mapping info is clearly given to Mapstruct by the second mapping function?

```
Flat          Composed
----          --------
- String a    - String a
              - Sub
- String b      - String b
- String c      - String c
```

.

```
@Mapper(uses = SubToFlatMapper.class)
public interface ComposedToFlatMapper {

    Flat map(Composed c); // Unmapped target properties: "b, c".
                          // Not OK because Sub mapping is defined in 
                          //    SubToFlatMapper and is used here :(
}

@Mapper
public interface SubToFlatMapper {

    Flat map(Sub s); // Unmapped target properties: "a".
                     //    (OK because 'a' is not in Sub)
}
```

Usage for clarity:

```
Composed composed = new Composed();
Sub sub = new Sub();

composed.setA("A");
composed.setSub(sub);

sub.setB("B");
sub.setC("C");

Flat flat = ComposedToFlatMapper.INSTANCE.map(composed);

// flat.getA() is "A", OK!
// flat.getB() is null, unexpected, should be "B"
// flat.getC() also null, should be "C".
```

`"B"` and `"C"` aren't mapped to `flat` because the generate code doesn't create the method for that.

I thought I had provided the required mapping information to the generator. It should generate inside `ComposedToFlatMapperImpl` when it sees the `Flat map(Sub s)` method.

*Edit*:

I didn't mention this before, but in the original question I could also use `update`-methods which are more flexible.

Now, assuming there is a new `Sub2` type. :

```
@Mapper(uses = {SubToFlatMapper.class, Sub2ToFlatMapper.class})
public interface ComposedToFlatMapper {

    Flat map(Composed c);

    void update(Composed source, @MappingTarget Flat target);
}

@Mapper
public interface SubToFlatMapper {

    Flat map(Sub s); 

    void update(Sub source, @MappingTarget Flat target);
}

@Mapper
public interface Sub2ToFlatMapper {

    Flat map(Sub2 s); 

    void update(Sub2 source, @MappingTarget Flat target);
}
```

.

```
Flat          Composed
----          --------
- String a    - String a
              - Sub
- String b      - String b
- String c      - String c
              - Sub2
                - String d
                - String e
```

Since `Flat` has no `Sub2` references just ignore it. There is no need to generate mapping code.

Comment: Your mapping method has `Composed` as the parameter and `Flat` as the target; is that what you actually meant, or should it be the other way around (as implied by the mapper class name)?

Comment: I added the use case

Comment: I fixed the class names. I hope it is better to read now.

Comment: I cant believe they made a mapping framework without this feature

Comment: Looking at the answer, your question doesn't need to be this long.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply flatten the nested source structure like so:

```
@Mapper
public interface ComposedToFlatMapper {

    @Mapping(target="b", source="sub.b")
    @Mapping(target="c", source="sub.c")
    Flat map(Composed c);
}
```

Comment: Yes, but this is a redundant information. The generator should see the mapping for the `Sub` type and use it. Other wise I don't need the `uses=` configuration. This is so obvious I don't think you can't see this.

Comment: When Mapstruct starts mapping the `Composed` type and sees the `Sub` type, it must use / delegate to the method  `Flat map(Sub s)` from `SubToFlatMapper` otherwise the composable model of Mapstruct is broken, if it forces me to specify hardcoded mappings. This last mile makes it genius IMHO.

Comment: That's not how it's working, and I'm not sure what you suggest can be made working actually. Assume there was `Sub2` with `d` and `e` and another used mapper `Sub2ToFlatMapper`. Which method, `subToFlat()` or `sub2ToFlat()`, should be called to obtain the instance of `Flat` to return from `composedToFlat()`?

Comment: Assuming your case, and if I declare update methods with `@MappingTarget` to update `Flat` types; then: For new `Sub2` types, use the methods declared in `Sub2ToFlatMapper` Let `ComposedToFlatMapper ` know there is a new mapper: `@Mapper(uses = {SubToFlatMapper.class, Sub2ToFlatMapper.class })` which handles the new `Sub2` types of `Composed`. During mapping, update the `flat` object with calls to update methods for occuring `Sub` and `Sub2` types in `Composed`.

Comment: I update the original answer, to make it more clear.

Comment: Yes, for update methods we could do what you suggest.

Comment: Ah finally, great! Maybe I can help with the implementation but I can't promise anything at the moment. If you already have a feature request could you please point me to that?

Comment: We don't have a feature request for this. You can file one [here](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues). Any help with implementing it will be more than welcome; you can find some starting points the [here](http://mapstruct.org/development/contributing/).